# angular handler from scope not being called in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that accepts a root scope defined function as a parameter.  It's not working, however. Absolutely nothing is happening.

here's where I call the directive (directivelist.html):

```
<select-list onsort="onSort" data-set="users" data-columns="columns" sort-by="UserName" reverse="false" selected-item="selection" details="showdetails" selected-index="index"></select-list>
```

the `details` is the part I'm having problems with (for some reason onsort is working).

here's the function from link (directive.js):

```
        scope.detailsHandler=function(item){
          console.log(item);
          scope.details(item);
        };
```

I know this works because it's being logged.  This part isn't (userController.js):

```
$scope.showdetails=function(user){
      console.log(user);
};
```

here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/N6nkW3e4gDdpQdtRC8ue?p=preview

Comment: showdetails is a function you can not have bidirectional bindings to functions using '=' in the directive use '&' instead and call it inside directives controller / link function.

Comment: simplify your demo so only pertinent code is available. Far too much effort expected from you wading through multiple files for people trying to help you

Comment: `showdetails()` doesn't return anything either

Comment: how do you know that onsort gets called? same reason as with showdetails you need to bind it using '&'

Comment: @charlietfl I think it's better to have the source code than asking people to post more or even worse guessing what they did wrong in the missing code. But you are absolutely right one should put some effort in creating a simplyfied demo.

Comment: no it's not.... superfluous code to wade through is a waste of time. Read the FAQ's on this site. Demo's should present enough code to replicate the problem....period

Comment: @bekite, check the demo now.  I'd disabled the sortby call back because the server side sort was not pretty. sortby is a function passed to the directive with '='.  when you click sort it will log to the console "I was called!"...the sortby function is in the usercontroller.js.

Comment: @charlietfl I get your point, which is why I called out the specific pieces of code that were in question.  However, this is a fairly complex angular directive and leaving out most of my code would've done a disservice.  If you're familiar with angular directives it should be pretty straight forward what you are looking for.

Comment: @Snowburnt I was wrong about tw binding on functions. Shame on me. How did you find out? All the docu I've read did it with '&'. Back to your question. Where do you invoce scope.detailsHandler? Couldn't find a call in the directive.

Comment: @bekite  starts on line 134 in the directive.  I actually got some of that code from this walkthrough: http://nadeemkhedr.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/build-angularjs-grid-with-server-side-paging-sorting-filtering/

Comment: @Snowburnt on line 134 you define the function. But where do you call it?

Comment: @bekite In the ng-click on line 21 in directivelist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive.js you overwrite the scope.details function on line 96. Simply remove it and scope.details will get called on the controller.